# Emit value from stream at most every x seconds

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, unirx

How can I construct an Observable stream that will emit a value, then skip subsequent values for x amount of time?

I have tried using `throttle` and a combination of `skipUntil` and `delay`, but I need all values emitted in the given interval to be ignored, not delayed.

Use case is that I have a button that can be clicked *at most* every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can in fact use `throttleTime` for this, it will discard the throttled results:

```
const source$ = fromEvent(this.myButton, 'click');

source$.pipe(
  throttleTime(1000),
)
```

See the docs:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html

Comment: Seems right, this might be an issue with UniRx (Unity implementation of Reactive Extensions)